# Where deploy Custom Provider DLL for ArcGIS Server if GAC is not an option

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, security

I have a client that has developed a custom Membership Provider for ArcGIS server and cannot deploy the provider to the GAC. Does anyone know where we could put the DLL such that the ArcGIS Security and Token applications can "see" it?

Thanks,
Carl

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is GAC deployment not an option?

Comment: Hi Petr, 
They are a big corporation and I'm told it is policy that prohibits them from deploying custom DLL into the GAC.  Do you know if ESRI recommends deployment into the GAC?

Answer (score 1):

You might try adding the reference to the web.config of those applications, provided you have access to the web server they are running on. You will need to keep the assembly binary in the Bin folder of each of those applications.

Answer (score 0):

to use the token service i had to create a bin folder with the dll's inside the token folder.

So it's looking like you'd need to duplicate the dll's inside each virtual directory for the web.config assembly look up to work.